# Getline function is undefined, even though <string> header is included

Tags: c++

I have looked at a few other questions regarding getline() not functioning, however most problems regarding the topic were due to the programmer not including the string header. I have the string header included however getline is still giving me error E0304 (which I have already looked into).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char input[100];
    getline(cin, input);
    cout << input << endl;
}
```

Comment: Also, please avoid `std::endl` when `\n` suffices.  `std::endl` flushes the buffer, while `\n` does not.  Unnecessary flushing can cause performance degradation.  See [`std::endl` vs `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/213907/9716597).

Comment: I for one have not spent time memorizing error codes. What is error E0304? The exact, full error message would be much more useful than just the error code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two forms of `getline`:

```
std::cin.getline(array, size); // reads into raw character array
getline(std::cin, string);     // reads into std::string
```

You should use a `std::string` instead of a raw character array:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::string input;
    getline(std::cin, input);
    std::cout << input << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The non-member `getline` only works with `std::string`. Use the `std::istream` member function `getline` for C-style strings:

```
std::cin.getline(input, sizeof(input));
```

Comment: Alternative: Use a `std::string` instead of an array.